# Using disk method in integration

Tags: integration, volume

I need to find the volume of the region defined by the inequalities
$$\begin{align*}y & <\frac 12\\0< y & <1-x^2\end{align*}$$revolved around the $x$ axis. I tried separating them and then integrating from zero to $0.707$ for $y<\frac 12$ and then from $0.707$ to one for $0<y<1-x^2$ but without a correct result.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your question. I don't understand what you are asking. Then tell us what you have tried. Are you stuck on some issue? Does your calculation give the wrong answer? We cannot help if we don't know what you need help with

Comment: LaTeX formulas need dollar signs around them—only part of your question is being displayed. (I'd edit them in, but am unsure of what's intended.)

Comment: You can click **edit** below the question to amend it. While you're editing, a preview should appear below the edit box.

Comment: Sorry about that.
I couldn't make them into formulas but I got them into bold

Comment: @YazanAl-Saif I've edited the question and embedded your picture. Is this what you want?

Comment: @FrankW. yes. Thank you for helping with that.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to double the answer you got? Your method only gives the volume for $x>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is simply the area enclosed by the graphs $y=1-x^2$, $y=\tfrac 12$, and the $x$ axis. Since the area is symmetric, consider only the region lying in the first quadrant. We'll double our answer to arrive at the area.

First, let's find the intersection of the two functions$$1-x^2=\frac 12\qquad\implies\qquad x=\frac 1{\sqrt2}$$

The region to the left of $x$ is simply a rectangle whose area is simply$$A_{\text{rectangle}}=\frac 1{\sqrt2}\times\frac 12=\frac 1{2\sqrt2}$$The area of the region to the *right* of $x$ can  be done by drawing a "slice" from the function to the $x$ axis. The height of that is simply$$r=1-x^2$$Therefore, rotating it about the $x$ axis and integrating, we get that the area of the right - hand side is simply$$A_{\text{right}}=\pi\int\limits_{\tfrac 1{\sqrt2}}^1\mathrm dx\,(1-x^2)^2+\pi\int\limits_0^{\frac 1{\sqrt2}}\frac {\mathrm dx}4$$
Hence, the total area is$$A\color{blue}{=2\pi\int\limits_{\frac 1{\sqrt2}}^1\mathrm dx\,(1-x^2)^2+2\pi\int\limits_0^{\frac 1{\sqrt2}}\frac {\mathrm dx}4}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

For $0\to1/\sqrt2$, you get$$\pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt2}(1/2)^2dx$$For $1/\sqrt2\to1$, you get$$\pi\int_{1/\sqrt2}^1(1-x^2)^2dx$$The final answer is double the sum of the above integrals due to symmetry.

Comment: I forgot to multiply by 2. Thank you for the answer